# Rails: sending emails, getting undefined method `model_name' for Mail::Message:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

My Rails skills is (to be kind) rusty so this is probably a newbie question. I'm trying to create a simple email sending form, but I keep getting:

```
NoMethodError in Mail#create
undefined method `model_name' for Mail::Message:Class
```

I'm pretty sure that my problem is in my controller, the relevant method looks like this:

```
def create
  @mail = Mail.new(params[:mail])
  MailMailer.send_mail(@mail).deliver
end
```

Thinks this line is causing the error `@mail = Mail.new(params[:mail])`. My Mail model class looks like this:

```
class Mail < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates :password, :presence => true
  attr_accessor :password, :to, :cc, :bcc, :from, :subject, :message
end
```

And my mailer looks like this:

```
class MailMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_mail(mail)
    mail(:to => mail.to, :subject => mail.subject)
  end
end
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://www.railsmine.net/2010/03/rails-3-action-mailer-example.html - good tutorial

Comment: I guess it's youir mailer template that tries to do I18n.. Could you post that code?

Comment: @Tigraine Nah, I haven't tried to do any localization if that was what you meant.

Comment: Is that really supposed to be `class Mail < ActiveRecord::Base`? Do you perhaps mean `ActiveModel::Base`?

Comment: @muistooshort Think so. I ran rails g model mail, and that was what I got. When I changed to ActiveModel I got: `uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Base`. I use rails 3.2.1, to clear things up.

Comment: @muistooshort You were almost right! I changed it to only be `class Mail`and it worked. Add this as an answer and I will give you some points, because I wouldn't have figured it out whiteout your comment. Think it's a bit strange that Rails defaults to `< ActiveRecord::Base`  when it didn't work. Hmm.

Comment: Should also note that I changed some code by following this tutorial: http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably right here:

```
class Mail < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates :password, :presence => true
  attr_accessor :password, :to, :cc, :bcc, :from, :subject, :message
end
```

Subclassing `ActiveRecord::Base` and including `ActiveModel::Validations` is a bit odd as AR already includes all the validation stuff. Mixing AR and `attr_accessor` is another sign that something strange is going on.

In your comments you note that you created this model with:

```
$ rails g model mail
```

And that tries to create a database-backed ActiveRecord model as that's almost always what people want. You might also run into trouble because `Mail` is already in use so maybe you want to use a different name.

If you just want a model that is just a temporary bag of data then you can do this:

```
class SomeEmail
  attr_accessor :password, :to, :cc, :bcc, :from, :subject, :message
end
```

You probably don't need the validations here but you can add them:

```
class SomeEmail
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates :password, :presence => true
  attr_accessor :password, :to, :cc, :bcc, :from, :subject, :message
end
```

but the validations won't be triggered unless you manually call `valid?` so there's no much point.

Finally, just adding `attr_accessor` doesn't give you a useful constructor so with all of the above changes, this:

```
@mail = SomeMail.new(params[:mail])
```

still won't do what you want as nothing in `params[:mail]` will get saved anywhere. So add an `initialize` implementation to your email class and a call to `valid?` to your controller.